# Filter a multidimensional array with similar characters

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a json file and I need to look for similar values in both columns.
For the JSON, It has 5,000 rows so I don't think looping to each is the right way.
My json looks like this:

```
{
   "code": "8485",
   "title": "A BAD DREAM",
   "artist": "KEANE"
 },
 {
   "code": "50957",
   "title": "A BIG HUNK O' LOVE",
   "artist": "ELVIS PRESLEY"
 },
 {
   "code": "55481",
   "title": "A BLUE GUITAR",
   "artist": "TANYA TUCKER"
 },
```

For example, I will look for things that has the letter 'B', it should look those that contain a letter 'B' for both the title and artist.

So what I did was converting the JSON to a multidimensional array. And I can't make the array_filter work with a multidimensional array.

Comment: What did you try with `array_filter()` and what were your results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can use `array_filter`

And you can use `strpos` to check if string contains a string.

Note: This will check if title **OR** artist **(either one)** has the search word or letter. If you are looking for both, see Syscall's answer. :)

```
$arr = '[
{
   "code": "8485",
   "title": "A BAD DREAM",
   "artist": "KEANE"
 },
 {
   "code": "50957",
   "title": "A BIG HUNK O\' LOVE",
   "artist": "ELVIS PRESLEY"
 },
 {
   "code": "55481",
   "title": "A BLUE GUITAR",
   "artist": "TANYA TUCKER"
 }
 ]
';

$arr = json_decode( $arr, true );

$search = "O"; /* Search letter O */

$result = array_filter( $arr, function( $v ) use ( $search ) {
    return strpos($v[ "title" ], $search) !== false || strpos($v[ "artist" ], $search) !== false;
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => 50957
            [title] => A BIG HUNK O' LOVE
            [artist] => ELVIS PRESLEY
        )

)
```

For more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Hey :) Almost same code :). But I read _"for both the title and artist"_ so I code `&&` instead of `||`. Am I right or I misunderstand ?

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure either, I guess OP will decide on that one. Haha

Comment: Thanks for the help! Now I got it. Actually both yours and Syscall helped me but I chose this one as the answer since it uses the OR. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Using `array_filter()` should works :

```
$cond = "B" ;
$result = array_filter($data, function($a) use ($cond) {
    return strpos($a['title'], $cond) !== false &&
           strpos($a['artist'], $cond) !== false;
});
```

This will check the matches on title **and** artist. If you want to check on the title **or** the artist, please check the Eddie's anwser :)

Comment: Thanks man! I could've made yours as the answer but Eddie's is much closer. Thanks!!